# FBSDKAppInviteContent works on WiFi but empty on LTE

Tags: swift, facebook-ios-sdk

On LTE the SFSafariViewController pops up but nothing loads while on WiFi everything works fine.

```
let appInvite = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
appInvite.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "A VALID LINK")!
appInvite.appInvitePreviewImageURL = NSURL(string: "A VALID URL")!
FBSDKAppInviteDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: appInvite, delegate: self)
```

Help!
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Hate Facebook SDK. Trash in logs, Invitable friends not working, FBSDKAppInviteDialog not loaded.  :(